# Change layout in adminhtml to columns with left sidebar on product edit and add new product page

Tags: magento2, product, adminhtml

In magetno1 product edit page looks with left sidebar tabs, but in magento2 it looks without tabs in left sidebar and it is too long page. How can i change page layout in adminhtml on add product page?